# error with two string[] and AreEqual in a C# Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

i have a problem with a c# test method.

it looks like:

```
public void GetRolesTest()
{
    RoleProvider target = new RoleProvider(); 
    string username = "FOO"; 
    string[] expected = new string[2];
    expected[0] = "Admin";
    expected[1] = "User";
    string[] actual;
    actual = target.GetRoles(username);
    Assert.AreEqual<string[]>(expected, actual);
}
```

the method which is tested just makes the following:

```
public override string[] GetRoles(string username)
{
    string[] output = new string[2];
    output[0] = "Admin";
    output[1] = "User";
    return output;
}
```

after running the test i get the following error:

```
Error in "Assert.AreEqual". Expected:<System.String[]>. Acutally:<System.String[]>.
```

can sombody tell me what is wrong there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you got your exception is that `Assert.AreEqual` will use default comparer for type which in case of `string[]` would be simple reference comparison (`actual` and `expected` are different objects - different references).

You can use collection assertion instead:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expected, actual);
```

Or, doing `true` verification with LINQ:

```
Assert.IsTrue(actual.SequenceEqual(expected));
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're testing here is whether `actual` and `expected` are the same array instance, which it is not the case. I would recommend testing the array contents explicitly, like this:

```
Assert.Contains( "Admin", actual );
Assert.Contains( "User", actual );
Assert.Equals( 2, actual.Length );
```

Depending on your unit testing lib the code may look slightly different, but I hope you see what I'm getting at.

Comment: i dont have a Assert.Contains

Comment: its running with CollectionAssert.Contains(actual, "Admin");